# R : data.table returns an empty row when the it actually exist

Tags: r, data.table

I have data that contains dates.

```
newdata <- data.table(example.dates)

> newdata
       start_date  paid_date
    1: 2014-08-01 2015-09-24
    2: 2015-08-01 2015-10-22
    3: 2015-10-01 2015-12-45
    4: 2015-11-01 2016-03-23
    5: 2016-12-01 2017-02-06
   ---                      
  100: 2018-02-05 2018-04-28
  101: 2018-03-02 2018-07-18
  102: 2018-06-14 2018-10-13
  103: 2018-08-16 2018-11-04
  104: 2018-10-19 2018-11-22
```

I have a function that calculates difference between dates in months

```
difference_month <- function(new_date, old_date) {
  start_date <- old_date %>% as.Date() %>% as.yearmon()
  end_date <- new_date %>% as.Date() %>% as.yearmon()
  diff_mon <- (end_date - start_date) * 12 
  return(diff_mon)
}
```

and added 'diff' column in newdata table.

```
newdata[,diff := difference_month(paid_date,start_date)]

> newdata
      start_date  paid_date diff
    1: 2014-08-01 2015-09-24  13
    2: 2015-08-01 2015-10-22  2
    3: 2015-10-01 2015-12-45  2
    4: 2015-11-01 2016-03-23  4
    5: 2016-12-01 2017-02-06  2
   ---                      
  100: 2018-02-05 2018-04-28  2
  101: 2018-03-02 2018-07-18  4
  102: 2018-06-14 2018-10-13  4
  103: 2018-08-16 2018-11-04  3
  104: 2018-10-19 2018-11-22  1
```

But, this appears when I want to see the rows that has 2 months difference.

```
> newdata[diff == 2]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: start_date,paid_date,diff
```

However, it works when I select a row that contains 2 months difference and use that to find the whole rows that contain 2 months difference.

```
x <- newdata[2][[3]]

> newdata[diff == x]
  start_date  paid_date diff
1: 2015-08-01 2015-10-22  2
2: 2015-10-01 2015-12-45  2
3: 2016-12-01 2017-02-06  2                      
4: 2018-02-05 2018-04-28  2
```

I checked str() and 'diff' was in numeric.

Why does this return empty rows when 2 months difference actually exist?

```
newdata[diff == 2]
```

Comment: Possibly a floating point error... Try rounding your diff-column to 0 digits and try again. Read this: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Answer (score 0):

Using `newdata` from the Note at the end, we note that [floating calculations can produce rounding error](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html) so round it at the end as shown below.  Also note that `as.yearmon` can convert the date columns directly so `as.Date` is not needed.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

newdata[, diff := round(12 * (as.yearmon(paid_date) - as.yearmon(start_date)))]
newdata[diff == 2]
```

giving:

```
   start_date  paid_date diff
1: 2015-08-01 2015-10-22    2
2: 2016-12-01 2017-02-06    2
3: 2018-02-05 2018-04-28    2
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
start_date  paid_date
2014-08-01 2015-09-24
2015-08-01 2015-10-22
2015-10-01 2015-12-45
2015-11-01 2016-03-23
2016-12-01 2017-02-06
2018-02-05 2018-04-28
2018-03-02 2018-07-18
2018-06-14 2018-10-13
2018-08-16 2018-11-04
2018-10-19 2018-11-22"

library(data.table)
newdata <- fread(Lines)
```